# Ubuntu(and also any other distro) not booting after installation on an old PC with CMOS

Tags: boot, system-installation

I just installed Ubuntu 20.10 on an old PC with CMOS setup utility. After the installation there are no boot options in CMOS. System just not booting and I am getting an error "No proper bootable device. Reboot and...". I have already tried Mint, Kubuntu, KDE Neon and now Ubuntu. There is one hard drive in the PC. I can't select anything in Boot Order (there's just nothing). Is it even possible to solve this problem on that old BIOS?

[image: CMOS main page]

System specs:

- 80 gb HDD
- CPU: Intel Pentium Unknown (2.40 GHz)
- GPU: none
- Motherboard: MSI g41m p33
- 2 GB RAM

I know this PC is bad, but anyway I want to recover it and give to my grandparents :D

[image: lspci output]

[image: lscpu output]

Comment: @Béné [lscpu](https://imgur.com/U7cx4X2)

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to diagnose. If you are able to boot off a live usb and complete the entire install, your PC is in principle compatible. I'd suggest:

- Try installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in order to rule out a bug with Ubuntu 20.10.
- (Bonus tip: As your PC is quite old you might want to look into using a lighter Ubuntu flavor such as Lubuntu or Ubuntu Mate.)
- Try to run [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) off a live USB. It's got an automatic repair option that is quite capable and alternatively you can generate a report that will help with further troubleshooting.

Good luck!

Comment: I tried with boot-repair. After successful repairing of boot, I am still getting an error "No proper bootable device...". I also tried to disable "Fast boot" in CMOS. In that case, if "Fast boot" is disabled, I am getting "Read error".